# Bash: Obtain latest semver from a given range - whilst reducing verbose conditional logic

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, refactoring, semantic-versioning

#### Background

I am developing a bash script to find the latest version within a given range from an array of [semver](http://semver.org/) versions.

The code/gist below *(example.sh)* includes a function named `log_latest_version_in_range` and it accepts an single argument. The argument specifies a package name and a [semver range](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#ranges). Here are a couple of examples of invoking the function:

```
# passing one comparator.
log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\<=1.0.1"

# passing two comparators.
log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\>=0.1.0\\ \\<0.2.6"
```

Invoking the function is analogous to how you might run an [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) for a package within a specific *semver* range. The argument passed to the function includes:

- a package name (e.g. `quux`) followed by an `@` symbol
- one or two *comparators* which specify:

  - an operator (i.e. `<`, `<=`, `>`, or `>=`)
  - a version (e.g. `0.2.6`)

*Note; the argument includes `\\` for escaping purposes to avoid word splitting. However that's slightly irrelevant, they will exist in the argument and that cannot be changed.*

*example.sh* in it's current form does successfully produce/log the desired outcome.

---

#### Question

To create the `versions_in_range` array the program loops over the `VERSIONS` array, and performs lots of conditional branching to ascertain whether the version is within range or not *(starting at line: 43)*. I'd like to refactor this if possible. Is there a more terse way to achieve that in bash?

---

#### example.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -ra VERSIONS=(\
    0.1.0 \
    0.1.1 \
    0.1.2 \
    0.2.0 \
    0.2.1 \
    0.2.2 \
    0.2.3 \
    0.2.4 \
    0.2.5 \
    0.2.6 \
    0.2.7 \
    0.2.8 \
    0.2.9 \
    0.2.10 \
    0.2.11 \
    0.2.12 \
    0.2.13 \
    0.2.14 \
    0.2.15)

log_latest_version_in_range () {
  local pkg_name comparator_count
  pkg_name=$(sed "s/@.*//" <<< "$1")
  comparator_count=$(awk -F " " '{ print NF }' <<< "$1")

  if [[ comparator_count -gt 2 ]]; then
    printf "%b" "Cannot specify greater than two comparators\\n"
    return
  fi

  # Get operator and version for each comparator in comparator set.
  local opr1 ver1 opr2 ver2
  opr1=$( sed "s/.*@//; s/\\\\//g; s/ .*//; s/[^>=<].*//" <<< "$1")
  ver1=$( sed "s/.*@//; s/\\\\//g; s/ .*//; s/.*[>=<]//" <<< "$1")
  opr2=$( sed "s/.*@//; s/\\\\//g; s/.* //; s/[^>=<].*//" <<< "$1")
  ver2=$( sed "s/.*@//; s/\\\\//g; s/.* //; s/.*[>=<]//" <<< "$1")

  # Create an array of all versions that are within range.
  local -a versions_in_range
  for v in "${VERSIONS[@]}"; do
    if [ "$comparator_count" == "1" ]; then
      if [ "$opr1" == ">=" ] && is_ge "$v" "$ver1"; then
        versions_in_range+=("$v")
      elif [ "$opr1" == ">" ] && is_gt "$v" "$ver1"; then
        versions_in_range+=("$v")
      elif [ "$opr1" == "<=" ] && is_le "$v" "$ver1"; then
        versions_in_range+=("$v")
      elif [ "$opr1" == "<" ] && is_lt "$v" "$ver1"; then
        versions_in_range+=("$v")
      fi
    elif [ "$comparator_count" == "2" ]; then
      if [ "$opr1" == ">=" ] && [ "$opr2" == "<" ]\
          && is_ge "$v" "$ver1" && is_lt "$v" "$ver2"; then
        versions_in_range+=("$v")
      elif [ "$opr1" == ">=" ] && [ "$opr2" == "<=" ]\
          && is_ge "$v" "$ver1" && is_le "$v" "$ver2"; then
        versions_in_range+=("$v")
      elif [ "$opr1" == "<" ] && [ "$opr2" == ">=" ]\
          && is_lt "$v" "$ver1" && is_ge "$v" "$ver2"; then
        versions_in_range+=("$v")
      elif [ "$opr1" == "<" ] && [ "$opr2" == ">" ]\
          && is_lt "$v" "$ver1" && is_gt "$v" "$ver2"; then
        versions_in_range+=("$v")
      elif [ "$opr1" == "<=" ] && [ "$opr2" == ">" ]\
          && is_le "$v" "$ver1" && is_gt "$v" "$ver2"; then
        versions_in_range+=("$v")
      elif [ "$opr1" == "<=" ] && [ "$opr2" == ">=" ]\
          && is_le "$v" "$ver1" && is_ge "$v" "$ver2"; then
        versions_in_range+=("$v")
      elif [ "$opr1" == ">" ] && [ "$opr2" == "<" ]\
          && is_gt "$v" "$ver1" && is_lt "$v" "$ver2"; then
        versions_in_range+=("$v")
      elif [ "$opr1" == ">" ] && [ "$opr2" == "<=" ]\
          && is_gt "$v" "$ver1" && is_le "$v" "$ver2"; then
        versions_in_range+=("$v")
      fi
    fi
  done

  # npm registry may not have version available within the range.
  if [ "${#versions_in_range[@]}" == 0 ]; then
    local mssg="Version cannot be found within range\\n"
    printf "%b" "$mssg"
    return 0
  fi

  # Get the last/latest version in range
  local latest_version="${versions_in_range[${#versions_in_range[@]}-1]}"

  printf "%b" "$latest_version\\n"
}

is_lt () {
  test "$(echo "$@" | tr " " "\\n" | sort -t. -k1,1nr -k2,2nr -k3,3nr -k4,4nr\
      | head -n 1)" != "$1"
}

is_gt () {
  test "$(echo "$@" | tr " " "\\n" | sort -t. -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n\
      | head -n 1)" != "$1"
}

is_le () {
  test "$(echo "$@" | tr " " "\\n" | sort -t. -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n\
      | head -n 1)" == "$1"
}

is_ge () {
  test "$(echo "$@" | tr " " "\\n" | sort -t. -k1,1nr -k2,2nr -k3,3nr -k4,4nr\
      | head -n 1)" == "$1"
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TESTING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Passing two comparators
printf "%b" "======= Two Comparators args ========\\n"
log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\>=0.1.0\\ \\<0.2.6"   # --> 0.2.5
log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\>=0.2.8\\ \\<=0.2.13" # --> 0.2.13
log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\<0.2.11\\ \\>=0.2.8"  # --> 0.2.10
log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\<0.2.15\\ \\>0.2.8"   # --> 0.2.14
log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\<=0.2.15\\ \\>0.2.8"  # --> 0.2.15
log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\<=0.2.0\\ \\>=0.1.0"  # --> 0.2.0
log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\>0.2.0\\ \\<0.2.6"    # --> 0.2.5
log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\>0.2.0\\ \\<=0.2.6"   # --> 0.2.6

printf "%b" "======== One Comparator arg =========\\n"
log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\>=0.2.10"  # --> 0.2.15
log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\>0.2.10"   # --> 0.2.15
log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\<=0.2.10"  # --> 0.2.10
log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\<0.2.10"   # --> 0.2.9

printf "%b" "=============== Other ==============\\n"
log_latest_version_in_range "quxxx@\\>0.2.14\\ \\<0.2.15\\ \\<=1.0.0"
    # --> Cannot specify greater than two comparators

log_latest_version_in_range "quxx@\\>0.2.14\\ \\<0.2.15"
    # --> Version cannot be found within range
```

---

**The correct output/log from running *example.sh* is as follows:**

> ======= Two Comparators args ========
>
> 0.2.5
>
> 0.2.13
>
> 0.2.10
>
> 0.2.14
>
> 0.2.15
>
> 0.2.0
>
> 0.2.5
>
> 0.2.6
>
> ======== One Comparator arg =========
>
> 0.2.15
>
> 0.2.15
>
> 0.2.10
>
> 0.2.9
>
> =============== Other ==============
>
> Cannot specify greater than two comparators
>
> Version cannot be found within range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I'd like to refactor this if possible. Is there a more terse way to achieve that in bash?"*

I finally chose to refactor how the values of the `versions_in_range` array were ascertained by utilizing `if` statements with multiple conditions.

Overall this reduced the use of `elif ...; then` statements, which in turn resulted in less instances of `versions_in_range+=("$v")`.

---

**Resultant refactored snippet** *(starting at line: 43)***:**

```bash
# Create an array of all versions that are within range.
local -a versions_in_range
for v in "${VERSIONS[@]}"; do
  if [ "$comparator_count" == "1" ]; then
    if ( [ "$opr1" == ">=" ] && is_ge "$v" "$ver1" ) ||
       ( [ "$opr1" == ">"  ] && is_gt "$v" "$ver1" ) ||
       ( [ "$opr1" == "<=" ] && is_le "$v" "$ver1" ) ||
       ( [ "$opr1" == "<"  ] && is_lt "$v" "$ver1" ); then
      versions_in_range+=("$v")
    fi
  elif [ "$comparator_count" == "2" ]; then
    if ( [ "$opr1" == ">=" ] && [ "$opr2" == "<" ] &&
          is_ge "$v" "$ver1" && is_lt "$v" "$ver2" ) ||
       ( [ "$opr1" == ">=" ] && [ "$opr2" == "<=" ] &&
          is_ge "$v" "$ver1" && is_le "$v" "$ver2" ) ||
       ( [ "$opr1" == "<"  ] && [ "$opr2" == ">=" ] &&
          is_lt "$v" "$ver1" && is_ge "$v" "$ver2" ) ||
       ( [ "$opr1" == "<"  ] && [ "$opr2" == ">" ] &&
          is_lt "$v" "$ver1" && is_gt "$v" "$ver2" ) ||
       ( [ "$opr1" == "<=" ] && [ "$opr2" == ">" ] &&
          is_le "$v" "$ver1" && is_gt "$v" "$ver2" ) ||
       ( [ "$opr1" == "<=" ] && [ "$opr2" == ">=" ] &&
          is_le "$v" "$ver1" && is_ge "$v" "$ver2" ) ||
       ( [ "$opr1" == ">"  ] && [ "$opr2" == "<" ] &&
          is_gt "$v" "$ver1" && is_lt "$v" "$ver2" ) ||
       ( [ "$opr1" == ">"  ] && [ "$opr2" == "<=" ] &&
          is_gt "$v" "$ver1" && is_le "$v" "$ver2" ); then
      versions_in_range+=("$v")
    fi
  fi
done
```